# Swift - find instance of class in array

Tags: arrays, swift, class

I would like to find the index of the *instance* of a class in an `Array` of that class.

For example:

```
var myArray: [MyClass] = []  

let myClass1 = MyClass()
myArray.append(myClass1)
let myClass2 = MyClass()
myArray.append(myClass2)
let myClass3 = MyClass()
myArray.append(myClass3)
...

let index = myArray.firsIndex(of: myClass2)
// Should return index = 1
```

Comment: What is actually happening? Does `MyClass` conform to `Equatable`?

Comment: No, that is the complexity here. But it should be possible as the Array contains pointers to each class instance, and I simply want to find the first occurrence of myClass2's pointer in that list of pointers

Comment: You didn't answer my first question. What actually happens when you run your code?

Comment: .firstIndex() does not work on non Equatable objects, and the (_ of:) overload is not implemented

Comment: Then you have your answer. As I hinted in my first comment, you need to conform to `Equatable`.

Comment: What if I don't want to implement the Equatable conformance? I don't have a property in the class that makes it unique (except its pointer) and find it inefficient to test all properties. Checking on the pointer's reference: is that not possible in Swift?

Comment: Then use `firstIndex(where: { $0 === myClass2 })`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having MyClass derive from NSObject, you could also have it implement the Equatable protocol and implement the equal-to operator.

```
class MyClass: Equatable {
    let name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    static func == (lhs: MyClass, rhs: MyClass) -> Bool {
        if lhs.name == rhs.name {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}

var myArray: [MyClass] = []

let myClass1 = MyClass(name: "myClass1")
myArray.append(myClass1)
let myClass2 = MyClass(name: "myClass2")
myArray.append(myClass2)
let myClass3 = MyClass(name: "myClass3")
myArray.append(myClass3)


if let index = myArray.firstIndex(of: myClass2) {
    print("Index of myClass2 = \(index)")
}
```

Output

> Index of myClass2 = 1